# Entity Framework core 2.1 Many To Many Select Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1

How would I create the following query using Linq?

```sql
SELECT product.name, product.code, category.Name FROM product 
INNER JOIN productCategories ON product.ID = productCategories.productID 
INNER JOIN category ON productCategories.categoryID = category.ID 
WHERE productCategories.ID = idToFind
```

Product & Category Classes:

```
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        this.Categories = new HashSet<Category>();
    }    
    public int ID { get; set; }    
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}


public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        this.Products = new HashSet<Product>();
        this.Children = new HashSet<Category>();
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentID { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried a few different things and can get the results if I only need columns from one table, but can not get details from both tables i.e. category name & product name.

Edit:
I have now added a JunctionClass

```
public class CategoryProduct
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }

}
```

and tried :

```
var results = _context.Product.Include(e => e.categoryProducts).ThenInclude(e => e.Category).Where(c=>c.categoryProducts.Category.ID==169).ToList();
```

But I still cant make it work.
Getting the error:

```
'ICollection<CategoryProduct>' does not contain a definition for 'Category' and no accessible extension method 'Category' accepting a first argument of type 'ICollection<CategoryProduct>' could be found
```

Comment: The code where you're querying your data is missing. What have you tried yourself so far? And show us the related Dbcontext code.

Comment: You need to explicitly specify a junction table.

Comment: I have now added a junction table, but I still cant make it work as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EF core, you need a junction table to map many-to-many relationships.

```
public class ProductCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
}

// DbContext
public DbSet<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }

public override OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<ProductCategory>()
           .HasOne(pc => pc.Product)
           .WithMany(p => p.ProductCategories);

    builder.Entity<ProductCategory>()
           .HasOne(pc => pc.Category)
           .WithMany(c => c.ProductCategories);
}

// Query
var result = await dbContext.ProductCategories
                     .Select(pc => new {
                         ProductName = pc.Product.Name, 
                         ProductCode = pc.Product.Code, 
                         CategoryName = pc.Category.Name 
                      })
                     .SingleOrDefaultAsync(pc => pc.Id == idToFind)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've added a junction table, but still can't get something that will return the data I need.

Comment: What's the problem? I've reproduced your query here. If you state your query in english I may see if the SQL matches up. This part was questionable to me `WHERE productCategories.ID = idToFind` You are looking up the junction table directly, which almost never happens. Were you trying to search by product id?

Comment: I didn't see the scrollbar. I was trying to do dbContext.Product, then get the categoryproducts and then the category. But the I kept getting syntax erros. The query you have works great.

Comment: Important to mention, that in EF core 5.0 you don't need junction table anymore: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew

Answer (score 0):

```
//Mock SomeData
List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
List<Category> category = new List<Category>();
//Linq
var result = products.SelectMany(product => product.Categories.SelectMany(productCategory => category.Where(category => category.ID == productCategory.ID).Select(category => new { category.Name, ProductName = product.Name, product.Code })));
```

Comment: When I try:var result = _context.Product.SelectMany(product => product.categoryProducts.SelectMany(productCategory => _context.Category.Where(category => category.ID == 169).Select(category => new { category.Name, ProductName = product.Description, product.Code })));  I get an error: must be reducible node

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var idToFind = 3;

var o = (from p in _products
         from c in p.Categories
         where c.ID == idToFind
         select new {ProductName = p.Name, ProductCode = p.Code, CategoryName = c.Name}).ToList();
```